# Using the database to pre-fill out a form in js.coffee file?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to edit this form so that the Serial Number field is already showing a serial number entered into the database as soon as you open it.

[image]

My code in my js.coffee file looks like this:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.add_sn_btn', ->
            parentRow = $(this).closest("tr")
            workorder_num = parentRow.children("td.workorder_num").children("a").text()
            dialog_div = $("#sn_save_div")
            $("#hid_wo_num").val workorder_num
            $("#sn_save").val ""
            todayDate = $.datepicker.formatDate 'mm/dd/yy', new Date()
            $("#prod_date").datepicker 'setDate', todayDate
            dialog_div.data "bin_model", parentRow.children("td.bin_model").children("span").text()
            dialog_div.data "parent_row", parentRow
            dialog_div.dialog 'option', 'title', "Add S/N to W/O "+workorder_num
            dialog_div.dialog "open"
```

I know that the line `$("#sn_save").val ""` is what is controlling what is being shown in that field. Anyone know how I can find a serial number from the database to put in this form?

I understand that this is a very specific question so I understand if this isn't worth anyone's time. I'll try and provide more information if you wish. Thanks

Comment: you'd have to query an ajax request to get data, then use it to set the input value

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? sorry